# How to access Environment sensors in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to access environment temperature data e.g Ambient air temperature, Device Temperature in Xamarin form.

**What I Tried:** 
I've already gone through Xamarin.Essentails documentation & checked following Nuget Packages but none of them met my requirements:

1. Plugin.Sensor
   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Sensors/
2. Xam.Plugin.DeviceMotion
   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.DeviceMotion/
3. Plugin.DeviceSensors
   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.DeviceSensors
4. Xamarin.Essential Official Documentation:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/

**PS:**
Please check Environment sensor provided by Android: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_environment

I want to achieve similar thing in Xamarin Form.

Comment: use  DependencyService to access platform specific code from  Forms

Comment: Not possible on iOS (things like battery temp are OS only|private APIs), on Android you can check the sensor manager for `STRING_TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE` support to determine if the device even has an ambient temp sensor (it is not a requirement for device OEMs to support any "environmental" sensors)